# What is the legal status and/or penalty for homosexualism in Uganda?

Tags: sexual-offences, homosexuality, uganda, africa

Corollary to the recent question on Somalia: what is the penalty for homosexuality in Uganda, and how commonly is it enforced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of laws in Uganda defining and penalizing homosexuality and related acts. The [Anti-Homosexuality act](https://www.parliament.go.ug/sites/default/files/The%20Anti-Homosexuality%20Act%2C%202023.pdf) penalizes a homosexual ct with life imprisonment. An attempt is penalized with up to 10 years in prison. Aggravated homosexuality receives the death sentence (most of the acts so defined fall under the broad penumbra of rape with a narrow understanding of competence, but also includes HIV provisions: and, it includes having a prior conviction for homosexuality of 'related offense'). Attempted aggrevated homosexuality is punished with 14 years. Child offenders are punished with up to 3 years. Homosexual child-grooming is punished with life or 20 years, depending on the nature of the grooming. Premise-maintenance related to acts prohibited by this act is penalized with 7 years, marriage (performing or being a party to) is 10 years. Promoting homosexuality is 20 years.

Rate of prosecution cannot be determined because this law was only enacted 5 months ago.

Comment: What is an understanding of competence?

Comment: I.e. under what circumstances would a person be assumed to not be competent to consent. Children usually are said to not be competent to consent, with provisions regarding age-differences in some jurisdictions. In Uganda, it is unqualified "under 18". Being disabled is included under triggers for aggravated homosexuality, also being a parent without age qualification.

Answer (score 1):

See the *[Anti-Homosexuality Act, 2023](https://www.parliament.go.ug/sites/default/files/The%20Anti-Homosexuality%20Act%2C%202023.pdf)*.

"Homosexuality" (defined in the act as performing a sexual act with a person of the same sex) is an offence with the risk of life imprisonment.

"Aggravated homosexuality" (which includes serial offences of "homosexuality") is an offence that is subject to the death penalty.

As of August 30, 2023, Amnesty International had reported two charges of "aggravated homosexuality" (*Amnesty International*, "[Uganda: Authorities must drop charges in death penalty case under Anti-Homosexuality Act](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2023/08/uganda-authorities-must-drop-charges-in-death-penalty-case-under-anti-homosexuality-act/)"). Although a day earlier, the BBC reported that the charge described was the first (*BBC*, "[Uganda's anti-LGBT laws: Man faces death penalty for 'aggravated homosexuality'](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-66645740)").